# How can I count the number of tables in an HTML page?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I believe the package `XML` has a solution. However, which function is the right one?

For example: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deaths_on_eight-thousanders

Answer (score 3):

I think there is 20 tables. Using `readHTMLTable` you can extract all the tables:

```
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deaths_on_eight-thousanders"

library(XML)
ll <- readHTMLTable(url)
length(ll)
[1] 20
```